# How can I populate a cell with concatenated values from another table?

Tags: excel

I have two tables first table contains ID, VendorId and Contact, I wish to populate the Contact column from the Contact table. I am able to get a value back, I'm missing the logic to find all values and concatenate the result.

This is what is have so far.

```
 =CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP([@VendorID],Contact,3,FALSE)," ",VLOOKUP([@VendorID],Contact,3,FALSE))
```

It returns John John.

This returns the correct value but it is hard coded.

```
=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(1,Contact,3,FALSE)," ",VLOOKUP(2,Contact,3,FALSE))
```

I would like the result to be John Cena.
I've tried different permutations using chatgpt but it isn't producing the correct result.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You may need `FILTER()` function then concatenate.

Comment: Agree with @Harun24hr. Use '`FILTER()` inside `TEXTJOIN` instead of the two `VLOOKUP()` functions to return an array of contacts for the VendorId in the Vendor table. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759